# How can we pass a static value in Azure Data Factory Copy acitvity mapping?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to pass a hard coded value into a column while using copy activity - how can this be done?

Comment: You can use additional columns at Source tab in copy activity.

Comment: Hi Harris - i just tried it and it worked fine.. but it doesn't let me re-use a column more than once against 2 diff target columns.. is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @azuresnowflake1 How about creating two addition columns?

Comment: Hi Steve - I am using this column as a place holder for 10-15 columns which will be replaced as and when the columns keep appearing but wanted to populate the columns with hard coded values until then.. so looking for a short cut

Comment: @azuresnowflake1 Per my experience, there is no short cut to do this in Copy activity.

Comment: yes - i posted this as a suggestion at adf customer feedback website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an addition column in Copy activity and pass your hard coded to it. Then use that column to do mapping.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy